# SQL Match first row after date in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get the datespan today is in, or first row after today's date if it doesn't exist, from the `Employment` table below? I would do something like this, but I'm not sure how to get only the first match from the other table.

```
SELECT * FROM User u
JOIN Employment e ON e.UserId = u.ID
WHERE e.To > GETDATE()
```

`User` table:

```
+----+------+
| ID | Name |
+----+------+
| 1  | Carl |
| 2  | Paul |
+----+------+
```

`Employment` table:

```
+--------+-------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| UserId | From        | To         |                                                 |
+--------+-------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| 1      | 2019-01-01  | 2019-12-31 |                                                 |
| 1      | 2020-01-01  | 2020-12-31 | <--- Correct. Date is within this datespan.     |
| 1      | 2021-01-01  | 2021-12-31 |                                                 |
| 2      | 2021-01-01  | 2021-12-31 | <--- Correct. Date is first after today's date. |
| 2      | 2022-01-01  | 2022-12-31 |                                                 |
+--------+-------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

EDIT: Sorry about the bad choice of mockup column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *seems* like you are just after the `TOP 1` after today's curent date?

```sql
SELECT U.ID,
       U.Name,
       E.[From], --FROM is a reserved keyword, I suggest choosing a different name for your column
       E.[To] --TO is a reserved keyword, I suggest choosing a different name for your column
FROM dbo.[User] U --USER is a reserved keyword, I suggest choosing a different name for your table
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1
                         [From], --FROM is a reserved keyword, I suggest choosing a different name for your column
                         [To] --TO is a reserved keyword, I suggest choosing a different name for your column
                  FROM dbo.Employment ca
                  WHERE ca.UserID = U.ID
                    AND ca.[To] >= CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) --TO is a reserved keyword, I suggest choosing a different name for your column
                  ORDER BY ca.[To]) E; --TO is a reserved keyword, I suggest choosing a different name for your column
```

Note, like all the comments say, I suggest renaming a lot of your objects. `FROM`, `TO`, and `USER` are all [Reserved Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and it is highly recommended to not use them for object names.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't used `CROSS APPLY` before. I'll see if that does the trick.